# Logstash grok square brackets

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I'm trying to get some sort of grok pattern to work with the following logging format :

```
*Sun 07:05:18.372 INFO  [main] [userID] perf - 0ms - select x from y
```

The problem I'm having is the field in square brackets that I've annotated here as userID. Sometimes this field is populated and at other times it is not. If I use the grok pattern below :

```
*%{DAY:Day} %{TIME:Time} %{LOGLEVEL:Loglevel}\s+(\[%{WORD:module}\]\s+)(\[%{HOSTNAME:id}\]\s+)%{GREEDYDATA:logline}*
```

It parses correctly as long as there is some data in the UserID field. If that field is empty ( example below ) it doesn't match. Any ideas gratefully received!

```
*Sun 07:05:18.372 INFO  [main] [] perf - 0ms - select x from y
```

Comment: Check with grokDebugger like http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result and also reference for matching pattern http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/patterns#

Answer (score 9):

Did you try to escape the brackets with backward slash?
As in `\[%{WORD:module}\]`

Answer (score 0):

the question is not about the escaping of the [] a simple zero or more operator (?) should do it:

```
(?\[%{WORD:module}?]\s+)
```

(the second ?)